Upgraded to 24.04, issue with images being dark
After upgrading to Ubuntu 24.04 I have an issue with some picture being too dark.
Here is an example of a picture viewing it with Image Viewer and Shotwell. Shotwell is showing it properly there :

I also have the issue in firefox. The green of the top logo is right, the bottom one is too dark, whereas on other computers and before upgrading they were looking identical.

If I save the image, it look different in shotwell and image viewer :

I have an nvidia card :
» lspci | grep -i nvidia
0a:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP108 [GeForce GT 1030] (rev a1)

Using proprietary driver :
» dpkg -l | grep -i nvidia-driver
ii  nvidia-driver-555                              555.58.02-0ubuntu0~gpu24.04.1                 amd64        NVIDIA driver metapackage


Tried the Nvidia Driver version 560, same issue.

Tried with Nouveau driver, the issue is gone.

Weird enough. I switched to 560, no luck. Uninstalled every Nvidia bits and rebooted on the Nouveau driver. No more color issue.
I reinstalled the 555 driver, so far so good, the issue is gone.
